# Which parameters were used by apt-get to install init scripts for a package?

Tags: apt, init.d

After removing the init script for hdparm with `# update-rc.d hdparm remove`, the wish is to re-install/fix/repair the hdparm init script. In other words to undo the update-rc.d removal.

Calling `# update-rc.d hdparm defaults` doesn't seem right:

```
# update-rc.d -n hdparm defaults
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: warning: hdparm start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match LSB Default-Start values (S)
update-rc.d: warning: hdparm stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (none)
```

Another [internet resource](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2004/01/msg00732.html) shows that `# update-rc.d hdparm start 07 S .` might be the correct re-installation command for hdparm.

But how to find out how the currently installed `apt-get install -t unstable hdparm` did exactly install its init script(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the pre- and post- installation and removal scripts in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.

```
% ls -1 /var/lib/dpkg/info/hdparm.*
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hdparm.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hdparm.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hdparm.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hdparm.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hdparm.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hdparm.preinst
```

`hdparm.postinst` (the script that is ran after successful installation) is the one that calls `update-rc`.